# Fixed horizontal form on mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form inside a fixed div.
[view on large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVLx2.jpg)
the problem is when I start to fill the form on mobile or small screens
[view on mobile or small screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpV2J.jpg)

I wanna push up this box when the user starts compiling it

I wrote this code to center the div

```
$.fn.centerBox = function () {
    $(this).css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'left': (windowVar.innerWidth() - $(this).width()) / 2,
        'top': (windowVar.innerHeight() - $(this).height()) / 2
    });
};
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do, please improve your question...

Comment: I want the user to see the field when he fills it in the small screens. This does not happen as in the picture